# Two MWE's that show how not to import things in Python, when you want to run a file in a subdir as main for testing purposes

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import, importerror, file-structure

Okay, pictured are the two MWE's and their failure messages.

In words, I can't naturally import, from the same subdirectory, into a module that I want to run as main for testing purposes.  That's the first screenshot.

The next screenshot shows that I cannot naturally import, from the project root, into a subdirectory module that I am similarly running as main for testing purposes.

### Visuals:

[image: Import in project subdir fails when running as main, and importing from subdir]

---

[image: Import from project subdir fails when running as main, and importing from project root]

What I don't want to do is hack my way through like I've been doing in all my projects with lines such as:

```
if __name__ == '__main__:
    import sys
    sys.append('..')
```

This is inelegant because it doesn't withstand changing the folder structure.

I've also tried putting in blank `__init__.py`'s into the subdirs and also tried putting in those the lines such as:

```
from .e import E
```

Nothing easy seems to work.  It's really a bummer when I can't handle basic file structures when importing things.

So what is the general fix that solves both of these issues for good and forever?

---

### Text Code:

`<proj root>/d.py`:

```
 class D:
     pass
```

---

`<proj root>/root.py`:

```
from b.a import A

print("import from project root main")
```

---

`<proj root>/b/a.py`:

```
from b.c import C

class A(C):
    pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('import from project subdir')
```

---

`<proj root>/b/c.py`:

```
class C:
    pass
```

---

`<proj root>/b/e.py`:

```
from d import D

class E(D):
    pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print("e can't import something from root")
```

First set entry point to `a.py`  and for the other error set entry point to `e.py`.

Thank you!

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first error, you create an `__init__.py` in the subdir `b` with the contents:

```
from .c import *
```

The same does not work for the root directory however.  But the most succinct way I've found, without having to do a `sys.path.append()` is to open up your project properties, and add precisely `..` to the Python Path:

In WingWare:

[image: Wingware Project Properties Dialog]

And that solves the second issue.  There is a warning when you add simply `..` that you should use absolute paths, but I'm okay with that.

If you work without an IDE simply modify the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable.

Happy Coding!